# Intellij suggestions (code completion) "eat" CPU

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

I use sass and jade plugins with IJ 13. The trouble is that when I start typing e.g. "d" for div the suggestion list takes a lot of time to be displayed (~2 seconds).

The things are a bit better with python files but still there is still some lag.

I increased the heap to the following, in the `idea.vmoptions` file  (`~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/idea.vmoptions`):

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx3g
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

but still no improvement.

How can I improve my laggy developing experience with IJ?

---

Update

I also noticed that after each typed letter (change) the IDE performs a code analysis. It might be the problem.

Comment: Dude, report an issue.

Comment: Is there a way to set code completion to activate when you type (say) 3 keys, instead of 1?